# Why cannot be inherited with different type arguments

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have seen many question around this, but none seens to be exactly what I am facing and I still don't understand what's wrong.
I have a class that implements two interfaces and these two interfaces extends from another interface with generics. Whoever it seens like I can't implement these two interfaces in the same class, as I have an error saying 'cannot be inherited with different type arguments'.

Interface with Generics:

```
public interface Observer<O> {
    void onEvent(O data);
}
```

Interface A:

```
public interface EventAObserver extends Observer<String> {
}
```

Interface B:

```
public interface EventBObserver extends Observer<Integer> {
}
```

Class that needs to listen both events and gets the error:

```
public class Listener implements EventAObserver, EventBObserver {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Integer data) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(String data) {

    }
}
```

All this trouble because somewhere else in my code I have a list of observers and I want to broadcast events just like:

```
for (Observer observer : observers)
    observer.onEvent(data);
```

Is it possible to solve this inheritance problem? Or should I try something entirely diffent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try something different because of type erasure for generics during runtime. This means during runtime the specified types for generics all are replaced by `Object`. And therefore the `onEvent` methods in `Listener` look the same during runtime.